# NoClassDefFoundError (4.0.4- 4.4.2)on Android Live Application

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

Recently I pushed an app(Proguard enabled) to play store but it start reporting NoClassDefFoundError on my activities (Not any library activity), these are happening on Android OS version 4.0.4 - 4.4.2 . Any help would be greatly  appreciated.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
def final myApplicationId = 'myapp.appModules.login'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId myApplicationId
        minSdkVersion 15
        resConfigs "en"
        targetSdkVersion 23
        compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1252'
/**        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }*/
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
    productFlavors
            {
                production
                        {

                        }
                staging
                        {

                        }
                quality
                        {

                        }
                dev
                        {

                        }
            }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport) {
    group = "Reporting"

    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    // exclude auto-generated classes and tests
    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class',
                      '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*',
                      'android/**/*.*', '**/*$ViewBinder*.*', '**/view/**', '**/vo/**/*.*']

    def debugTree = fileTree(dir:
            "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/production/debug",
            excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    additionalSourceDirs = files([
            "${buildDir}/generated/source/buildConfig/production/debug",
            "${buildDir}/generated/source/r/production/debug"
    ])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes:
            ['**/*.exec', '**/*.ec'])

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        xml.destination = "${buildDir}/jacocoTestReport.xml"
        csv.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
        html.destination = "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco"
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile project(':ImageCropper')
    compile project(':dropboxChooserSDK')

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/comscore.jar')


    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
}
```

Comment: can I see your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @Ironman I have updated the question please check it

Comment: @Ironman Please check